# Не работает move_uploaded_file PHP

Tags: php

На сервере лежит скрипт php который выполняет загрузку файла на сервер:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/home/admin/web/asdf.ru/public_html/some-project/py/docs/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile));
?>
```

Но при попытке загрузить файл выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жалуется на `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile));` (10 строка кода)

Comment: А что вам не понятно в словах "permission denied"? права на папку для записи какие?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на some-project xxx. а на скрипт755

Comment: кто такой some-project? и что такое xxx?

Comment: some-project это папка где лежит скрипт и в общем весь сайт. xxx стандартные права

Comment: нет таких прав как xxx....    папка some-peroject может иметь одни права, а папка куда картинка летит - нет.... также права скорее всего нужны не 755 а 775. Потому что скрипт работает скорее всего от www-data  ...  права должны быть для юзеров user:www-data

Comment: сможете подсказать как использовать команду chown в этом случае? по разному пробовал, результата никакого

Comment: ну как  минимум `sudo chown -R user:www-data /путь/к/папке/проекта` ... где вместо `user` надо написать пользователя системы......  и потом `sudo chmod 775 -R /путь/к/папке/загрузки/картинок` ...... возможно 775 нужно тоже для папки проекта ставить